# How to asynchronously upload an image from an air app on iOS/Android using as3 and php?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I want to upload an image from an air app running on iOS or Android to a server using php.
I need to have a functional UI while the file is uploaded, and I cannot have the user having to select the image from a gallery as it is already captured using CameraUI.

Ideally I should be able to get ProgressEvents during the upload to update the user on the progress.

Comment: I feel like I have tried almost everything I can find by googling, but everything seems to fail one way or another. I am sure I must be missing something, because I cannot imagine this should be any difficult at all...

Comment: What was the last thing you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: We need to know where you are stuck on that to-do list.. But anyway to stop app freezes you handle smaller data in parts so you send smaller "pieces" of your image bytes to the server (copy first 65535 bytes then next and so on until end). Use timer if necessary.. Your PHP side should then combine the pieces together as one file (becomes like original).

Comment: the operation is no different than what you would do in a web app. There's no freeze involved and the progress can be monitored easily. Do you not know how to upload an image to a server?

Comment: Thank you for your help.
My main problem shoved to be a very slow JPGEncoder in AS3. When changing to using JPEGEncoderOptions instead things went 100x + times faster.

Answer (score 1):

When exporting for iOS or Android JPGEncoder is extremely slow.
I changed to using JPEGEncoderOptions instead, and things are working now!

Comment: To make it clear for others: You switched to _flash.display.BitmapData.encode_ function in combination with _JPEGEncoderOptions_